# Who is George, the manager of Ahnernebe?

Tags: all-around-type-moon

In All Around Type Moon spin-off, the cafe Ahnernebe is run by George.

[image: George]

He has the main antagonist aura behind him.

[image: George's aura]

So who is George? Is he a reference to anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my guess he refers to the voice actor **Jouji Nakata**, the CV of Kirei Kotomine(in Fate), Souren Araya(in Kara no kyoukai) and Nero(in Tsukihime). When he is angry the image of the three characters will show up behind him. Besides, Jouji in Japanese sounds very similar to George in English.

[image: Jouji Nakata][image: George]

Comment: added picture of him that look like in manga, you can remove it if I got the wrong person